# What are the benefits of the factory method pattern aside from subclassing?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, factory-pattern

While using the .NET Color struct, I found myself wondering why Microsoft chose to use the factory method pattern for this struct (knowing that the factory method pattern is mainly used for subclassing and that structs cannot be subclassed).

I gave *Wikipedia* a try. It confirmed my thoughts, without actually giving out the answer :

> Although the motivation behind the factory method pattern is to allow
>   subclasses to choose which type of object to create, there are other
>   benefits to using factory methods, many of which do not depend on
>   subclassing. Therefore, it is common to define "factory methods" that
>   are not polymorphic to create objects in order to gain these other
>   benefits. Such methods are often static.

So, tell me, what are these **other benefits** of the factory method pattern?

For example, how could I benefit from calling `Color myColor = Color.FromArgb(255,255,255)` instead of `Color myColor = new Color(255,255,255)` ?

*(note that the second method isn't actually possible since the Point struct has no parameterized constructor because of the factory method pattern it uses)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason why I use such method is because they are effectively *named* constructors. For example for `Color` the order in which the components get specified isn't obvious without a name. Usually `ARGB` is used, but sometimes you also see `BGRA` or even an entirely different color space like `HSV`. Putting the used color order into the method name, makes the code more self documenting.

Another advantage is that static methods support type inference. For example with `Tuple<...>`, you can simply use `Tuple.Create(1,5)` instead of the more verbose `new Tuple<int,int>(1,5)`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain more? What part of the implementation of the Color struct is a factory?

Also, it seems like you are mismatching the "Factory" AKA (Abstract Factory), and the "Factory Method" patterns. Both are creational patterns. But they are different, and are used for different purposes.

Ref

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern
```

Comment: I was talking about the factory method pattern. I clarified my question.

Answer (score 0):

With software *in general*, an factories are often used to reduce dependencies. Only the factory needs to know about all the types it can create, the conversions it must apply, and many dependencies may be abstracted from the client -- the clients which deal with the factory do not need to see the interface for each type the factory may create.

Since languages are interpreted and compiled very differently, this affects some languages more than others. Thus, and abstract factory can hide entire libraries behind its interface.

So CodeInChaos pointed out it's really a named constructor in this case -- but *could* there still be physical dependence which can be abstracted in this scenario? **YES!**. Let's create an example scenario using colors.

Let's say there is a class which defines a color. This class has multiple specializations and varying members in order to accurately represent each specialization of color available -- let's say Grayscale, RGB, and CMYK. A naive conversion method is capable of producing illegal colors already. With a factory method, you could use a type to abstract that complexity by requesting an arbitrary color's type to be converted by its color model. That is, the conversion of an RGBA conversion to Grayscale is one function, and the conversion of CMYK to RGBA is another function. An abstract color representation may have a method named `asRGBA()` to handle this conversion, where each specialization or subtype may offer vastly different implementations of the conversion.

Well alright, that abstracts some complexity and keeps all our colors legal (RGB cannot represent all CMYK values). Seems over-complicated? **No**. In reality, there are more color representations. As well, there are color profiles which may be specific to devices (e.g. a monitor), or specific to other targets (e.g. the printer that is connected). Conversion functions for these profiles are far more complex.

For a basic color representation, we would have to inject many dependencies to handle all of these devices and targets. Well crafted factory methods can abstract all this and use optimized implementations for these conversions, while reducing dependencies.

That's a contrived example (I'm not a C# dev), but it does illustrate how factory methods may be used to reduce complexity, and to minimize dependencies.

Comment: You're talking about the subclassing advantage, which isn't part of my question.

Comment: @asmo dependency reduction in this context is certainly not confined to subclassing. your question's been revised 4 times - i answered the original.

Comment: @asmo I've updated my answer in response to your question's updates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the term "factory methods" would normally be used to refer to methods which return a struct, since *all* methods which return a struct return an instance which didn't exist previously (except, ironically, struct constructors invoked from vb.net).

Answer (score 0):

This quote from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) suggests a purpose:

> When you create a struct object using the new operator, it gets created and the appropriate constructor is called. Unlike classes, structs can be instantiated without using the new operator. If you do not use new, the fields will remain unassigned and the object cannot be used until all of the fields are initialized.

The factory method pattern, in the context of a .NET struct, **prevents uninitialized instances**.